# WCF Web Service / Date Format YYYY-mm-dd / Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, visual-studio-2022

WCF Web Service URI: https://www.onlinembe.de/wsdl/OnlineMbeSOAP.wsdl

For the function call ShipmentsListRequestRequest it is possible to specify DateFrom and DateTo as parameters. The format for this is YYYY-mm-dd.

https://www.onlinembe.de/wsdl/documentation.html

Is it possible to control how the DateTime format is transferred?
If I pass a DateTime class in the autogenerated class it does not work.The parameter is ignored.

```
ShipmentsListRequestRequest request = new ShipmentsListRequestRequest();
ShipmentsListRequestResponse shipmentsListResponseResponse;

request.RequestContainer = new ShipmentsListRequestType();
request.RequestContainer.System = SystemType.DE;
request.RequestContainer.Credentials = credentials;
request.RequestContainer.InternalReferenceID = "1";
request.RequestContainer.StoreID = "0000";
request.RequestContainer.DateFrom = DateTime.Today;
request.RequestContainer.DateFromSpecified = true;
request.RequestContainer.DateTo = new DateTime(2022, 8, 20);
request.RequestContainer.DateToSpecified = true;

shipmentsListResponseResponse = await client.ShipmentsListRequestAsync(request);
```

Comment: Is it a case of control transfer parameters like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters)?

Comment: Do you mean "type by value" or "type by reference"? The request is working, but it ignores my date setting.

Comment: Print out the current date format on the console to determine whether to convert. And the date format is usually used in this form :`DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")`.

Comment: Is it possible to view the entire SOAP message that is sent to the server?

Comment: By implementing the interface [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.beforesendreply?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) `BeforeSendReply` method can obtain a message sent to the server.